# How can I make another click on escape key that will return to the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerCameraMouseLook cammouselook;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
            PlayerCameraMouseLook.mouseLookEnable = false;
            cammouselook.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when pressing the escape key it's loading the main menu scene.
And in the main menu I have NEW GAME button but not RESUME.

Instead making a resume button I want that pressing the escape key again when the main menu scene is loaded it will return back to the game to the current position it is. Either if it's in a middle of a cutscene or just idle in the game.

So when pressing the escape key again it will back to the game and continue from the last point.

Another sub question : Should I use : LoadSceneMode.Additive ? Or when switching between the game play scene and the main menu it should remove the current active scene and then load the next one ?

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

The main menu scene is at index 0 the game scene at index 1.

[image: Main Menu]

What I tried :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Variables
    private bool _isInMainMenu = false;
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public PlayerCameraMouseLook cammouselook;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (!_isInMainMenu)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                PlayerCameraMouseLook.mouseLookEnable = false;
                cammouselook.enabled = true;

                // -- Code to freeze the game
                mainGame.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                // -- Code to unfreeze the game
                mainGame.SetActive(true);
            }

            _isInMainMenu = !_isInMainMenu;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Hierarchy :

The script is attached to the Back to main menu gameobject. And all the game objects are under Main Game.

[image: Hierarchy]

First time when pressing the escape key it's loading to the main menu and main menu scene to the hierarchy. Second time pressing on the escape key it's starting the game over like a new game and removing unloading the main menu.

In both cases the game scene is stay in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to add your `main menu scene` with the flag `Additive` as you mentioned.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Variables
    private bool _isInMainMenu = false;
    public PlayerCameraMouseLook cammouselook;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (!_isInMainMenu)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                PlayerCameraMouseLook.mouseLookEnable = false;
                cammouselook.enabled = true;

                // -- Code to freeze the game

            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                // -- Code to unfreeze the game
            }

            _isInMainMenu = !_isInMainMenu;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the variable `_isInMainMenu` : it will track if you are in the main menu or not. Depends on the value, the **Escape key** will behave differently.

**Note :** I suggest you to type the current index of the scene in `LoadScene / UnloadSceneAsync`, unless you may want to change their index. In this scenario, type the scene name (Methods overload).

Now what I mean with `// -- Code to freeze the game` depends on your game :

- You can have a unique GameObject that contains all the others GameObjects your scene has, and `Enable / Disable` it

```cs
myBigGameObject.SetActive(true/*or false*/);
```

- Have a logic in MonoBehaviour to freeze the game while your in the main menu.
  For example you can use the bool `_isInMainMenu` in **Update()** to stop them from doing their job ;

For example in this MonoBehaviour I created as an example :

```cs
public class ExampleMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update ()
    {
        if (_isInMainMenu)
            return;
        print("I'm running !");
    }
}
```

- Have a Collection (List as an example) that stores every `top hierarchy GameObjects` and enable/disable them all as needed to behave the same as above.

Depends on how your code is, there is many other options.
I will highly suggest you to do the *first* or *third* option, unless you have a better approach.

The thing is, if you want to go back to the main menu, it shouldn't be very expansive (loading time, memory usage, ...) so you can disable GameObject from the `main scene` (third point) to restore them back quickly when you leave the `main menu` without reloading the entire scene. This would lead you to use serialization and deserialization.

---

**Edited : Typo**

Comment: If you can look please at my question I edited it with what I tried so far. It's not working good. The second escape click to back to the game like resume make it start the game like a new game.   I guess I didn't make it right.

Comment: What do `PlayerCameraMouseLook.mouseLookEnable = false and cammouselook.enabled = true` do ? Did you take care of them when you unfreeze the game ? Be careful with the _magic method_ `OnEnable()` when you unfreeze the game if any MenoBehaviour has it.

Comment: I found that in my Hierarchy I have under mainGame a EventSystem. Once I disabled the EventSystem object in the hierarchy before running the game the escape key is now working fine. The EventSystem is added to the Hierarchy by one of the canvas or other ui I added sometime. It's not a eventsystem that I added on my own for something specific. So maybe I should delete the eventsystem object ?

Comment: The event system thats what made the game to start over again on the second escape key. When the event system object is disabled when running the game then it's working fine. Nut do I need the event system ? Here is a screenshot of the event system : https://imgur.com/a/bT4Nqf4

Comment: The EventSystem component will allow your UI to use raycasting (detect mouse click on UI elements for example), or even Raycaster for 2D/3D physics elements. It shouldn't make your code fail. Is case you don't need it (Buttons for example will require it), you can safly disable it. That's weird this component makes your code fail.

Comment: I did a mistake. I created a new question with what I wanted. I didn't explain it good enough. My game start with the main menu. If you can look at this link on my question. And the logic I want it to be with a screenshot of my hierarchy. https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-logic-start-my-game-with-the-main-menu-and-then-to-start-a-new-game-or-resume-a-game.753974/